# How to rename url

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-boot

I am new to web application development and I am currently developing a web application in Spring Boot which is published under this URL:

```
https://reverseproxy/application_name/login.html
```

I want this to be changed into:

```
https://reverseproxy/application_name/login
```

I know if I use Thymeleaf templates then I can achieve this. But instead of that by just using HTML can I make my URL look like this to the users?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

[source (with explanations)](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Answer (score 0):

> Spring-mvc provide a way to do this by creating a controller and map
>   `/login` to `/login.html`

But if you want to achieve that without any line of java code and just using html you can add a new rule to reverse proxy (as you are using one) to map `https://reverseproxy/application_name/login` call to `https://reverseproxy/application_name/login.html`

Answer (score 0):

What might also do the job is [Spring MVC Content Negotiation](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml) when setting the default content type to MediaType.TEXT_HTML